# Difference between two dates not considering the year in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask about the difference between two dates and its not consider the year for check the birthday. I find the query to check the two dates and its consider the year.

For example,

```
   SELECT to_date(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(dateofbirth,'DD-MM-YYYY')
   FROM employees;
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Question is not clear, can you describe it more clearly?

Comment: First, neither of those `to_date` calls shld be needed; the first is certainly wrong, the second ought to be as hopefully your `dateofbirth` field is a `DATE` already. Secondly, what are you trying to find - how many days until their next birthday, or something else?

Comment: I just need difference between two dates and its consider date and month, not consider the year and it should return no of days between that two dates.

Comment: So if you compared `sysdate` of `2013-04-17` with `dateofbirth` of `1980-04-21`, you'd want a negative answer, `-4`? And `+4` if you compared with `1980-04-13`?

Comment: What is the difference between `28th February` and `1st March`, ignoring the year? The answer could, justifiably, be either 1 or 2. So I think you need to come up with a carefully considered, consistent, definition before asking us to solve it.

Comment: (And if you decide to say it's always 1 and just ignore leap years, you need to, oppositely, give us what rule you want to apply when one or both of the dates *is* `29th February`)

Comment: Yes.. That's only i ask.. Sorry my english was not well..

Comment: It's totally and utterly useless to convert `SYSDATE` (which is already a `DATE`) to a `DATE` using to_date(). Additionally it is bound to produce errors depending on different NLS settings.

Comment: If the person already had his/her birthday this year, do you want a negative number ("x days past your birthday") or the number of days until the next birthday (in the next year)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simplistic approach is to look at the ordinal number of the dates within their year, using the [`DDD` format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924):

```
to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'DDD')) - to_number(to_char(dateofbirth,  'DDD'))
```

With some sample data in a CTE:

```
with t as (
    select 1 as id, date '1980-04-21' as dateofbirth from dual
    union all select 2 as id, date '1980-04-13' as dateofbirth from dual
    union all select 3 as id, dat
)
select id, dateofbirth, to_char(sysdate, 'DDD'), to_char(dateofbirth, 'DDD'),
    to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'DDD'))
        - to_number(to_char(dateofbirth,  'DDD')) as days
from t
order by id;

        ID DATEOFBIR TO_ TO_       DAYS
---------- --------- --- --- ----------
         1 21-APR-80 107 112         -5
         2 13-APR-80 107 104          3
         3 29-MAR-80 107 089         18
```

But as Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in comments, you need to define, or at the very least understand and accept, what will happen with leap years. This approach doesn't do anything clever, but might be good enough for whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
SQL> SELECT (TO_DATE('20120525', 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('20100101', 'YYYYMMDD')) diff_in_days
  2         ,TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20120525', 'YYYYMMDD'), TO_DATE('20100101', 'YYYYMMDD')))
  3         ,TRUNC(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20120525', 'YYYYMMDD'), TO_DATE('20100101', 'YYYYMMDD'))) / 12) num_years
  4         ,MOD(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20120525', 'YYYYMMDD'), TO_DATE('20100101', 'YYYYMMDD'))), 12) num_months
  5  FROM   dual
  6  /
```

which will produce this

```
DIFF_IN_DAYS TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('  NUM_YEARS NUM_MONTHS
------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         875                             28          2          4
```

[Source](http://oracletuts.net/tutorials/how-to-calculate-difference-between-dates-in-oracle-sql/)

Comment: I just need difference between two dates and its consider date and month, not consider the year and it should return no of days between that two dates.